# How to replicate SQL queries on remote device?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-2.7, mariadb, embedded-linux

I have 2 similar devices, running embedded Linux distribution based on Yocto Krogoth and both of them have 512 MB memory. These devices are connected via Ethernet. Both of them have `MariaDB  10.1.30` running.

I want to have a possibility to create some kind of primary-secondary relationship. So every `INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE` performed on primary device will replicate on secondary.

Dumping database on the secondary device every N seconds is not suitable. Also i tried to configure replication as described here https://www.lexiconn.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-set-up-selective-master-slave-replication-in-mysql/ but it does not work - `mysqld` service just doesn't start without writing any errors in its log.

I wonder if there are any other ways to perform this kind of replication? Maybe some software ways  (Python 2.7 is used for system services on that device).

This is `my.cnf` file:

````
#password                   = password
port                        = 3306
socket                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld_safe]
err-log                 = /var/log/mysql.err

[mysqld]
user                        = mysql
port                        = 3306
socket                  = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file                    = /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid
log-error                   = /var/log/mysqld.err
basedir                     = /usr
datadir                     = /var/lib/mysql
skip-external-locking
# skip-networking
ignore-builtin-innodb
default-storage-engine              = myisam
skip-name-resolve
# bind-address                  = localhost
max_sp_recursion_depth = 255
event_scheduler = ON
sql_mode = NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO
max_connections = 1000
back_log = 512
thread_cache_size = 128
thread_handling = pool-of-threads
query_cache_size=10485760
query_cache_type=ON
stored_program_cache=2048
join_buffer_size=1048576
#general-log
#general-log-file = /var/log/queries.log
#log-output = file
#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d```

Thanks in advance.
````

Answer (score 0):

OK, do it.  The main *potential* problem is whether the IP addresses are static.

What errors are happening?

A caution:  512M is *very* tight.  Show us your `my.cnf`; there may be some things to shrink.

Comment: Primary device has static IP address. Secondary device obtains dynamic address from primary via DHCP.

Comment: @gopher_topinambur - Since the Secondary connects to the Primary (not the other direction), your approach should work.